# Position of "of which" in the sentence

Tags: word-order, possessives

In a post here I found that both following sentences are correct..is that true? Is the first one really grammatically correct?

> A camera of which the wires go through the wall.
>
> A camera, the wires of which go through the wall.

I thought that "camera of which" is not correct..? Dictionary I have says "changes the importance of which is.."..so could I say "changes of which the importance is..?

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to vote to close this one

Comment: I did, though. Q: "How come both these sentences are correct?" — A: "Both these sentences are correct." Well, duh.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical and so too is 'A camera whose wires go through the wall'.